# C++ find size of ofstream

Tags: c++, ifstream, ofstream, string-length

I have code that currently does something like the following:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("file.txt");
fout<<"blah blah "<<100<<","<<3.14;
//get ofstream length here
fout<<"write more stuff"<<endl;
```

Is there a convenient way to find out the length of that line that is written at the stage I specified above? (in real life, the int 100 and float 3.14 are not constant and can change). Is there a good way to do what I want?

EDIT: by length, I mean something that can be used using fseek, e.g.

```
fseek(pFile, -linelength, SEEK_END);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want `tellp`. This is available for output streams (e.g., ostream, ofstream, stringstream).

There's a matching `tellg` that's available for input streams (e.g., istream, ifstream, stringstream). Note that `stringstream` supports both input and output, so it has both `tellp` and `tellg`.

As to keeping the two straight, the `p` means `put` and the `g` means `get`, so if you want the "get position" (i.e., the read position) you use `tellg`. If you want the `put` (write) position, you use `tellp`.

Note that `fstream` supports both input and output, so it includes both `tellg` and `tellp`, but you can only call one of them at any given time. If the most recent operation was a write, then you can call `tellp`. If the most recent operation was a read, you can call `tellg`. Otherwise, you don't get meaningful results.

Comment: I have made a related question about how to handle the outputs from tellg/tellp since they may overflow a long long. I'm adding a link here to help others in the future: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825351/c-how-to-add-subtract-tellp-tellg-return

Answer (score 3):

You can get the current position using `tellg` or `tellp`:

```
fin.tellg();  // postition of "get" in istream or iostream (fstream)
fout.tellp(); // position of "put"  in ostream or iostream (fstream)
```

Comment: why, i'm printing to find in the code sample, it is output not input

Answer (score 3):

Use ostream::tellp(), before and after

Answer (score 2):

fout::tellp() will give you position of the next byte to be written to.