# C++ how to add/subtract tellp(), tellg() return

Tags: c++, iostream, ofstream

Say I wanted to get the difference (in int) between two tellp() outputs.

The tellp() output could be huge if a big file is written so it is not safe to say store it inside a long long. Is there a safe way to perform a operation like this:

```
ofstream fout;
fout.open("test.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
int start = fout.tellp();
fout<<"blah blah "<<100<<","<<3.14;
int end = fout.tellp();
int difference = end-start;
```

Here, I know that the difference between end and start can definitely fit in an int. But end and start itself could be very massive.

Comment: `long long` would be enough for a few Exabytes. How large files do you plan to support?

Comment: It just seems very ugly to have to cast it into a long long, there's no built in addition/subtraction for this return type?

Comment: The files should be at maximum 1GB. For that, it seems a long is sufficient?

Comment: For 1GB, `long` would indeed be enough.

Comment: 1GB should be enough for everybody.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The return type from `ofstream::tellp` (and `ifstream::tellg`) is a `char_traits<char>::pos_type`. Unless you really need your final result to be an `int`, you probably want to use `pos_type` throughout. If you do need your final result as an `int` you still probably want to store the intermediate values in `pos_type`s, then do the subtraction and cast the result to `int`.

```
typedef std::char_traits<char>::pos_type pos_type;

ofstream fout;
fout.open("test.txt",ios::out | ios::app);
pos_type start = fout.tellp();
fout<<"blah blah "<<100<<","<<3.14;
pos_type end = fout.tellp();
int difference = int(end-start);
// or: pos_type difference = end-start;
```