# objdump doesn't show size for ostream class

Tags: c++, linux, elf, dwarf

I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << sizeof(std::cout) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Compile it with `g++ -g main.cpp` (it prints 272 on my OS)

After that I execute `objdump --dwarf=info a.out` and see next debug info entry (die) for `ostream`:

```
<2><c5a>: Abbrev Number: 41 (DW_TAG_class_type)
<c5b>   DW_AT_name        : (indirect string, offset: 0x5fa): basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >
<c5f>   DW_AT_declaration : 1
<c60>   DW_AT_sibling     : <0xc77>
```

Actually `ostream` is just typedef for `basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char>>`
Die doesn't contain attribute with size (`DW_AT_byte_size`) and I can't understand why. There is no other die-s for ostream class in executable file but compiler should know size of that class (it prints a size with `sizeof`). So my question is: how can I get right size for `ostream` class from dwarf info with `objdump`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ find size of ofstream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16825055/c-find-size-of-ofstream)

Comment: @SirDigbyChickenCaesar my question has nothing with that question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [spec](http://dwarfstd.org/doc/DWARF4.pdf) DW_AT_Declaration indicates the DIE is describing a declaration rather than a definition; you need to look in an object file that contains the definition.

Answer (score 1):

The language-independent objdump utility dumps symbols in an object file. std::ostream is a class, and not an object.

The std::cout object comes from the C++ library. Use obdjump on libstdc++.so, to find std::cout.

Comment: If sources were compiled with debug info it's possible to find in object file info about all functions, variables, types etc from these sources. I understand that `cout` object is defined in shared library but I'm just curious why I can't get dwarf info for `basic_ostream` class because compiler can use that info (e.g. for sizeof operator).

Comment: @eXXXXXXXXXXX FWIW, although cout's size is not in the DWARF section of the executable, it is in the symtab, e.g. `00601060 g O .bss  00000110 _ZSt4cout@@GLIBCXX_3.4`.